# Insurance Policy Probability Question

Tags: probability

[image]

Hi, I was wondering if anyone could help me consolidate my answer/workings for this question.

So I have initially just stated that there are 100 people in each policy group just to make the percentages a nice number of people.

I know from the figures that 40 women have policy A and 26 women have policy B making a total of 66 women having a policy in general.

Then because we are choosing a policy from the women selection we know that Policy B will have a 26/66=0.394 chance of being selected and Policy A will have a 40/66= 0.606.

Is my method correct or am I going wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know from the figures that 40 women have policy A and 26 women have policy B

That is wrong! You know from the figure that 40% of the policyholders are female, thus if you have 100 guys total only 20 are female and only $20\cdot0.40=8$ are female AND policy A

With similar reasoning, starting with 1000 policyholders total, you have that 288 are females and 80 are female with policy A. Thus the requested probability is

$$\frac{80}{288}\approx 27.78\%$$

---

In these situation a table like the following is very useful to represent the problem

[image]

(I used 1000 guys to avoid "non-integer" guys)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Super Helpful! :) . I totally understand where I went utterly wrong now.

Comment: @TaylorS. : added an useful (IMHO) table

Comment: Ah great! This makes so much sense to do that.

Comment: So I take it for the probability I just make the percentage a figure. So P(A)=0.278 to 3 d.p.?

Comment: @TaylorS. yes,$ P(A|F)=\frac{P(A,F)}{P(F)}=0.2778$ Once you derived the table (that is the bivariate distribution) you can answer to any request by simple ratios